# How to disable the quantity field in the product detail page in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce

I need to hide the "quantity" field (where one enters the quantity before adding to cart) in Woocommerce on the product detail page, and only show the "add-to-cart"-button, which would then put the quantity of 1 in the cart. The reason is because I gather the quantity based on a Gravity Forms.

Answer (score 66):

- Edit your product.
- Click "Inventory".
- Check the box that says "Sold Individually"

Comment: This is best for a product by product basis. Otherwise, filtering `woocommerce_is_sold_individually` works best for blanket application to all products.

Answer (score 49):

The safest way is to use WordPress builtin hook or filter

```
/**
 * @desc Remove in all product type
 */
function wc_remove_all_quantity_fields( $return, $product ) {
    return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'wc_remove_all_quantity_fields', 10, 2 );
```

You can also remove Quantity selector in other product type, you can found our more here http://www.sutanaryan.com/how-to-remove-product-quantity-selectors-woocommerce/

**Please be warned:** using this option effictively makes it impossible to have a product more than once in your shopping cart. Subsequently clicking "Add to cart" will trigger a warning that this product can only be in your cart once. This might not be desirable for everyone.

Comment: This is by far the best answer here and should be accepted as the answer to the question.

Comment: agree! it overwrites the setting in product data tab -> inventory. be aware of that.

Comment: @Reinoud van Santen I dont think so - it relies on a hook that might change also `wc_remove_all_quantity_fields` seems like it could remove ANY quantity field..

Comment: Please be warned: using this option effictively makes it impossible to have a product more than once in your shopping cart. Subsequently clicking "Add to cart" will trigger a warning that this product can only be in your cart once. This might not be desirable for everyone.

Comment: Voting down didn't help, if the above solution is not 100% or have some conflict or implications then please provide 110% solutions that works, this might old but it help other looking for solution.

Comment: This can be simplified to: `add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', '__return_true' );`

Comment: Why is this method "the safest"? I think it would depend on use case. My only concern is that anyone reading this may reasonably think it's "unsafe" to use @John Chandler's answer which is also perfectly fine.

Comment: i dont like this solution, since the warning you already placed there. to me its a difference, to hide the input and to manipulate ALL products to be sold individually, just to make the field dissapear..

Comment: See my answer if you want to know how to have a product more than once without the quantity field

Answer (score 16):

[image]

There is no need to use a plugin or edit function.php just check the option shown in the image above.

Comment: I love it when I think something is going to be complicated, and then I run into an answer like this and it's just easy.

Comment: Curiously enough, I have this and yet the quantity is still shown in the checkout.

Answer (score 4):

There is a free plugin to remove the quantity selectors that might work for you.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woocommerce-remove-quantity-fields/

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple way to do it just in product single page, and keeping the quantity counter in cart. Just put the following code in functions.php

```
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'quantity_wp_head' );
    function quantity_wp_head() {
    if ( is_product() ) {
        ?>
    <style type="text/css">.quantity, .buttons_added { width:0; height:0; display: none; visibility: hidden; }</style>
<?php
 
    } else { ?>
   
    <?php }
    }
```

You can check the woocommerce documentation here: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/remov-product-content-based-on-category/

Comment: sorry, but this solution is just ugly. insert a style tag on pages that are single product..? why not use the default wordpress style.css with a decent selector in the first place?!

Answer (score 3):

```
.quantity, .product-quantity{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

There´s no need for plugin, for example you can hide it using css. But woocommerce let you sell just 1 product, with no choise to add more of same item to cart. Take a look on woocommerce->settings. It´s all there.

Comment: I dispise this notion of hiding functionality in Wordpress via CSS. CSS is for presentation.

Comment: This should not be done using css - the woocommerce product settings do this

Comment: "But woocommerce let you sell just 1 product, with no choise to add more of same item to cart" Did you read that part?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [**`woocommerce_quantity_input_min`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.1719) and [**`woocommerce_quantity_input_max`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.1718) hooks by **setting both quantities to 1**.

In fact, in the `/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php` template, the quantity field will be automatically hidden if **min** and **max** have the same value.

```
// hides the quantity field on the product page
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'hide_woocommerce_quantity_input', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_max', 'hide_woocommerce_quantity_input', 10, 2 );
function hide_woocommerce_quantity_input( $quantity, $product ) {
    // only on the product page
    if ( ! is_product() ) {
        return $quantity;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Answer (score 0):

The template you need to edit is `single-product/add-to-cart/variation-add-to-cart-button.php`.

So you can simply copy this template in your own theme and edit it to remove the quantity field.
It would become something like:

```
<?php
/**
 * Single variation cart button
 *
 * @see     http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.5.0
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;
?>
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button">
    <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $product->single_add_to_cart_text() ); ?></button>
    <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo absint( $product->id ); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an edge case that is not being handled by other answers to this question, 
the 'is sold individually' option of woocommerce effectively removes the quantity input but prevents the same product to be added multiple times to the cart

In a use case where you have a product with custom attributes where you don't want the quantity to be editable but you still want to allow a user  to add the same product to the cart with different attributes, then the 'is sold individually' option will not work

What you need in this case is this filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', function ( $qty, $item_key, $item ) {
    if ( ! empty( $item['custom_data'] ) ) { //Here check for your custom attribute
        return sprintf( '1 <input type="hidden" name="cart[%s][qty]" value="1" />', $item_key );
    }
    return $qty;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the product (or the store as a whole) to 'sold individually' as explained by the other answers here now works for me, but I also found another solution: Hiding the quantity field on a particular page ID. If anyone wants the field to show on certain pages and not others for whatever reason, consider this alternative:

```
.page-id-11111 .woocommerce .quantity .qty {
    Display:None!important;
}
```

This will let people add multiple times to cart, and edit quantities at checkout if they do, while still hiding the quantity field on the product shortcode/page. More info here: [Remove quantity field from Woocommerce, without preventing multiple cart additions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917152/remove-quantity-field-from-woocommerce-without-preventing-multiple-cart-additio) (I have reworked the site so this solution isn't necessary for me anymore, but this may help someone.)

Answer (score 0):

This code disables the quantity field only on the product page. You can still click on the add to cart button multiple times or change the quantity in the cart.

```
function theme_remove_quantity_field( $return, $product ) {
    if(is_product()){
        $return=true;
    }
    return $return;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_sold_individually', 'theme_remove_quantity_field', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score -3):

It's very simple, in `woocommerce\includes\abstracts\abstract-wc-product.php`, find `abstract-wc-product.php` file in woocommerce

Find below code in page

```
$availability = sprintf( __( '%s in stock', 'woocommerce' ), $this->get_total_stock() );
```

replace this code with

```
$availability = sprintf( __( '%s in stock', 'woocommerce' ),'');
```

Comment: Very simply you will end up in a mess after an update :)